# Does 'As Good As Random' Have a rigorous definition in identification strategies?

Tags: econometrics, experiment-design, causality, identifiability

If using an identificaton strategy such as differences in differences, Regression Discontinuities, or IV's, I see the phrase 'as good as random' used alot. Does this have a rigorous definition, or is it just another way of saying what we are trying to accomplish when ensuring exogeneity of the above estimators?

Comment: "Does this have a rigorous definition...?" No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The phrase "as good as random" is often just used instead of (conditional) igonorability (no open back-door paths) in observational natural experimental settings. In my opinion, this is bad practice and shows the authors insecurity of explicitly stating that the back-door criterion is assumed to hold - likely because they think it does not.

Answer (score 0):

As good as random is a way to state that - although it did not occur as an actual lottery and cannot be described as a result of an actual random draw (such as can be conducted in randomized controlled trials) - the result of a certain policy still ended up with an assignment that should be as balanced as a random draw.